# Why we need to repeat trait bounds that were specified in trait definitions?

Tags: rust

I have a function like this:

```rust
pub fn foo<T: FromStr<Err = impl Display>>() -> T {
    T::from_str("123").map_err(|e| println!("{e}")).unwrap()
}
```

It has a trait bound on `T` and a trait bound on that trait's associated type `Err`. I want to create an "alias" for these bounds. Here is my first trial:

```rust
pub trait AliasTrait: FromStr
where
    <Self as FromStr>::Err: Display,
{
}

impl<T: FromStr<Err = impl Display>> AliasTrait for T {}

pub fn foo<T: AliasTrait>() -> T {
    T::from_str("123").map_err(|e| println!("{e}")).unwrap()
}
```

However rustc complains that

```
error[E0277]: `<T as FromStr>::Err` doesn't implement `std::fmt::Display`
  --> src/main.rs:19:15
   |
19 | pub fn foo<T: AliasTrait>() -> T {
   |               ^^^^^^^^^^ `<T as FromStr>::Err` cannot be formatted with the default formatter
   |
   = help: the trait `std::fmt::Display` is not implemented for `<T as FromStr>::Err`
   = note: in format strings you may be able to use `{:?}` (or {:#?} for pretty-print) instead
note: required by a bound in `AliasTrait`
  --> src/main.rs:13:29
   |
11 | pub trait AliasTrait: FromStr
   |           ---------- required by a bound in this
12 | where
13 |     <Self as FromStr>::Err: Display,
   |                             ^^^^^^^ required by this bound in `AliasTrait`
help: consider further restricting the associated type
   |
19 | pub fn foo<T: AliasTrait>() -> T where <T as FromStr>::Err: std::fmt::Display {
   |                                  ++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0277`.
```

But when I change the `AliasTrait` to

```rust
pub trait AliasTrait: FromStr<Err = <Self as AliasTrait>::Err> {
    type Err: Display;
}

impl<T: FromStr<Err = impl Display>> AliasTrait for T {
    type Err = T::Err;
}
```

Then it works.

[Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=172d000f73b7b1551b7f3961cbdb5e9f)

I do not quite understand why the first `AliasTrait` implementation needs to repeat the trait bounds specified in its definition. Because all types that implement `AliasTrait` should have satisfied these bounds. This is totally redundant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a (very old) rustc bug: [#20671](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/20671).